# convert date rows to columns without pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, crosstab

i have a sql table that contains date, time, employee ID and punch type(IN, OUT), the data is like the follow:

```
EMPID   Date        Time        Punch type
123     2015-08-01  08:00 AM    EMPIN
123     2015-08-01  01:00 PM    EMPOUT
123     2015-08-01  02:30 PM    EMPIN
123     2015-08-01  07:30 PM    EMPOUT
123     2015-08-02  09:30 PM    EMPIN
123     2015-08-02  11:00 AM    EMPIN
123     2015-08-02  06:00 PM    EMPOUT
123     2015-08-03  08:00 AM    EMPIN
123     2015-08-03  06:00 PM    EMPOUT
123     2015-08-03  02:30 AM    EMPOUT
123     2015-08-04  08:00 AM    EMPIN
123     2015-08-04  06:00 PM    EMPOUT
```

I want to display the time of punches under dates but without pivot table, because i can't apply the aggregate function on type time, i have already tried the pivot but it didn't work.

And i want to display them as the follow:

```
EMPID       Punch type   2015-08-01   2015-08-02   2015-08-03   2015-08-04
123         EMPIN        08:00 AM     11:00 AM     08:00 AM     08:00 AM
123         EMPOUT       01:00 PM     06:00 PM     06:00 PM     06:00 PM
123         EMPIN        02:30 PM     09:30 PM
123         EMPOUT       07:30 PM     02:30 AM
```

, my code is:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '20150801'
,@EndDate DATETIME = '20150831'
if NOT EXISTS (
SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects o
WHERE o.xtype IN ('U')  
AND o.id = object_id(N'tempdb..#TABLE')
        )

CREATE TABLE #TABLE (date DATETIME,numberOFWorkingHour INTEGER,empID NVARCHAR(6),time time,funckey NVARCHAR(20))

insert #TABLE

SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(12),a.date) AS Date
,dbo.GetWorkingHourPerDay(a.date,a.empID) as numberOFWorkingHour
,a.EMPID
,a.time
,a.FuncKey
FROM
@EmployeesTable et
LEFT JOIN PERS_Attendance a ON a.empID = et.empid
LEFT JOIN PERS_EmployeeProfile EmpP ON EmpP.ID = a.EmpID

WHERE a.Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

GROUP BY a.empID,a.Date,a.time,a.FuncKey
--select * FROM #TABLE order by date

DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), date,103 ) as varchar(10)))   
FROM
(  
SELECT a1.date FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT date
FROM #TABLE 

WHERE Date BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
)a1
) t

FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  
).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')   
,1,1,'')  
SET @query = 
' SELECT EMPID,funckey,' + @cols + '
FROM   
(
SELECT t.EMPId,convert(varchar(20), t.date,103)date,t.time,t.funckey, t.numberOFWorkingHour
FROM #TABLE t
)src  
pivot
(  
AVG(time)
for date in (' + @cols + ')  
) p WHERE 1=1'

EXEC(@Query)

if object_id('tempdb..#TABLE') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #TABLE
END
```

AS i have mentioned, the time type don't work with pivot, so with what do i replace it?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add some sample data and expected results please?

Comment: yes of course, please see the edit

Comment: Why don't you use `MAX()` instead of `AVG()`?

Comment: MAX() function only return the maximum time data..i already tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code give the correct output:

```
create table #table(empid int, pdate date, ptime time, ptype varchar(10));
go
insert into #table(empid, pdate, ptime, ptype) values
    (123, '2015-08-01', '08:00 AM', 'EMPIN')
    , (123, '2015-08-01', '01:00 PM', 'EMPOUT')
    , (123, '2015-08-01', '02:30 PM', 'EMPIN')
    , (123, '2015-08-01', '07:30 PM', 'EMPOUT')
    , (123, '2015-08-02', '09:30 PM', 'EMPIN')
    , (123, '2015-08-02', '11:00 AM', 'EMPIN')
    , (123, '2015-08-02', '06:00 PM', 'EMPOUT')
    , (123, '2015-08-03', '08:00 AM', 'EMPIN')
    , (123, '2015-08-03', '06:00 PM', 'EMPOUT')
    , (123, '2015-08-03', '02:30 AM', 'EMPOUT')
    , (123, '2015-08-04', '08:00 AM', 'EMPIN')
    , (123, '2015-08-04', '06:00 PM', 'EMPOUT');

declare @cols nvarchar(max), @query nvarchar(max);
declare @StartDate date = '20150801', @EndDate date = '20150803'
declare @ParmDefinition nvarchar(200) = '@StartDate date, @EndDate date'

SELECT @cols = STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), pdate,102)) 
        FROM (  
            SELECT DISTINCT pdate FROM #table
            WHERE pDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
        ) t
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')   
,1,1,'')
;

Select @cols 

Set @query = '
With order_by_empid(empid, pdate, ptime, ptype, n) as (
Select empid, pdate, ptime, ptype
    , n = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by empid order by pdate, ptime)
    From #table
    WHERE pDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
), match_days(start, empid, pdate, ptime, ptype) as (
    Select o1.pdate, o2.empid, o2.pdate, o2.ptime, o2.ptype From order_by_empid as o1
    Inner Join order_by_empid as o2 on o1.n = o2.n-1
    Where o1.ptype = ''EMPIN''
    Union All
    Select o1.pdate, o1.empid, o1.pdate, o1.ptime, o1.ptype From order_by_empid as o1
    Where o1.ptype = ''EMPIN''
), data(empid, pdate, ptime, ptype, n) as(
    Select g.empid, g.start, g.ptime, g.ptype
        , n = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by empid, start order by pdate, ptime)
    From match_days as g
)
Select piv.empid, piv.ptype, '+@cols+' 
From data as d
Pivot (
    max(ptime)
    for pdate in('+@cols+')
) as piv
order by piv.empid, piv.n;
';

exec sp_executesql @query, @ParmDefinition, @StartDate = @StartDate, @EndDate = @EndDate;

go
drop table #table
```

I used several CTE to break it down. It is easier to show and explain how it works...

- First CTE `order_by_empid` orders data by date and time for each empid.
- Based on this ordered list, `match_days` is used to pair IN and OUT together even though OUT is sometimes on the next day. It gets the correct IN date for each OUT line.
- CTE `data` then order them by the correct date and time and Pivot can then be used to pivot it.

Output:

```
empid | ptype  | 2015-08-01       | 2015-08-02       | 2015-08-03       | 2015-08-04   
123   | EMPIN  | 14:30:00.0000000 | 21:30:00.0000000 | 08:00:00.0000000 | 08:00:00.0000000
123   | EMPOUT | 19:30:00.0000000 | 18:00:00.0000000 | 18:00:00.0000000 | 18:00:00.0000000
```

Comment: hello @Julien Vavasseur what if i have dynamic columns, not only these 4 days?
in this case i will use the dynamic query of pivot as i mentioned in my question..so how could i adjust it with your code?

Comment: This can be added to your @@query variable. Replace your main select by most of my query and your @@cols.

Comment: hello @Julien Vavasseur, i have a problem when user have only,two punches, the punch out is in the second day, your answer works in case the employee have more than two punches as 3 punches in the same day, and the last punch out is allocated at the second day, please see the edit for the answer

Comment: please see the edit of the question @Julien Vavasseur

Comment: there is a problem with your data: 2015-10-05 14:40:00 EMPIN is after 2015-10-05  01:30:00  EMPOUT => 1:30:00 is before 14:40:00

Comment: ok dear @Julien Vavasseur, it was an employee fault, thank you

Answer (score 0):

you could convert time to number of seconds, than find an average value and convert it back to time
try to use

```
convert(time,dateadd(second,AVG(datediff(second,0,time)),0))
```

instead of

```
AVG(time)
```